# Black and white aerial image classification with ecognition fails to execute

Tags: ecognition

I am trying to classify an image in ecognition, it gives a good number of well shaped polygons, but when I try to execute the classification, it only shows one class; I've done the same process for color images, that's why I believe the error has to do with the B&W aerial photo.

Comment: I found out I was missing to "Apply NN standard to features"